# How can I list files in a folder from JavaScript in cocos2d-x?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-js

I need to list all the files in the `res` folder from a JavaScript script in cocos2d-x. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

To keep compatibility with Cocos2d-html5 a JavaScript-only solution is most desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have access to the filesystem. This is for security purposes.

However, HTML5 does allow access to a sandbox filesystem. Cocos2D has [an implementation of this sandbox](https://github.com/mcscooter/cc2d-html5-sb) access, but it doesn't appear to be official support. It's not too likely that utilizing this sandbox will be something that's cross platform. In this situation, you'll likely have to create platform specific code.

Comment: Currently I know more or less the names of the files I need to access so I keep fishing but this solution generates a lot of errors and is definitely not good for production code...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but in the following this file: http://cocos2djs.org/demos/tile-maps I found this construct:

```
var map = new TMXTiledMap(
    { file: path.join(__dirname, '../resources/TileMaps/iso-test.tmx')})
```

The github site also has tutorials on using javascript for cocos2d

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. I'm looking for an API to list available files in a folder. I can read any file y name, there is no problem with that.